# How to insert data into a li, inputted by the user? JS

Tags: javascript

I am very new to JavaScript and am trying to create a to do list. I am trying to create a function that takes the data entered by the user and display it in a list below.

I can't seem to figure out how to get the value that has been inputted and display it below in a li.

HTML:

```
     <div>
        <input type="text" id="task" placeholder="What do you need to do?" />
        <button class="btn" onclick="createToDo()">Submit</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul id="list">
          <li id="taskInput"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

JS:

```
function createToDo() {
  var input = document.getElementById("task").value;
  var ul = document.getElementById("list");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild((element.attribute = input));
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

I have figured out how to manually insert text by using:

```
  li.appendChild((document.createTextNode("Input"));
```

but of course this returns the text.

I'm not sure if I have approached the function totally wrong or it is a minor solution but any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `element` in `element.attribute`? The argument to `appendChild()` must be an element. If you just want to set the text of an element, use `li.innerText = input`

Comment: You can use `document.createTextNode(input)` -- leave out the quotes so it uses the variable value.

Comment: Isn't that what it does?

Comment: `li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input));`

Comment: Oh wow thank you!!! 

So I had it right, I just had to remove the ""'s

Comment: Of course. That's how you use variables.